# C++ boost serialization ERROR : [uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error-No such process]

Tags: c++11, boost, c++14, c++17

I get an error **" libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::archive::archive_exception: input stream error-No such process "** in my program.

My Program :

```
class fruits{
public:
    void set(int apple, int mango, int banana){
        m_apple = apple;
        m_mango = mango;
        m_banana = banana;
    }

int apple(){return m_apple;}
int mango(){return m_mango;}
int banana(){return m_banana;}
private:
    int m_apple, m_mango, m_banana;
    friend boost::serialization::access;

template<typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive & arc, unsigned int version){
    arc & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_apple);
    arc & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_mango);
    arc & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(m_banana);
}
};

void save(std::string fname){
    fruits _fruits;
    _fruits.set(1, 2, 3);
    std::ofstream of(fname.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive of_xml(of);
    of_xml & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_fruits);
    of.close();

}

void load(std::string fname){
    fruits _fruits;
    std::ifstream inf(fname.c_str());
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive inf_xml(inf);
    inf_xml & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(_fruits);

    std::cout<<"apple : "<<_fruits.apple()<<" mango : "<< _fruits.mango()<<" banana : "<<_fruits.banana()<<"\n";

}

int main(){

    std::string fname = "fruits.xml";

    save(fname);
    load(fname);  // this function gives error

    return 0;
}
```

Is I'm doing something wrong Guys?, when restoring data from xml file. However if I change `of_xml(of)` to `of_xml(of, boost::archive::no_header)` and `inf_xml(inf)` to `inf_xml(inf, boost::archive::no_header)` the program executed successfully. How to get ride of this error guys?